# О преобразовании речи в текст

Tags: письменность

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ к ВОПРОСУ

Скоро С. исполнится 6 лет, в связи с чем он начал учиться набору и редактированию текстов  на экране компьютера. Вот почему меня заинтересовал вопрос о средствах преобразования устной речи в письменный текст [на экране компьютера], которые следует использовать при обучении ребёнка русскому языку.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вот такой сервис https://speechpad.ru/
Есть программа RealSpeaker.
Вообще, программы, которые используют сервисы google довольно хорошо справляются с задачей, но требуют подключения к интернет.

Не стоит доверять обучение автоматизирующим программам, т.к. нет такой программы, которая могла бы допускать меньше ошибок, чем человек. Да и ручной набор развивает моторику + память(ИМХО)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Средство преобразования устной речи в письменный текст [где угодно] при обучении ребёнка:

**уроки русского языка и литературы**.

Полностью, все части этих уроков. Нельзя вычленить из этих уроков какой-то один хитрый и быстрый способ, отбросив всё остальное (серебряной пули нет).